# flutter background video fullscreen problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using this code to add a background fullscreen video to my app, It works good on the virtual device but not good on physical devices!

```
            new Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: <Widget>[
          FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: SizedBox(
                width: controller.value.size?.width ?? 0,
                height: controller.value.size?.height ?? 0,
                child: VideoPlayer(controller)),
          ),
        ]),
```

Comment: could you edit your answer and include the image, as it seems that it got embeeded with the code part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
 SizedBox.expand(
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: videoController.value.size?.width ?? 0,
                  height: videoController.value.size?.height ?? 0,
                  child: VisibilityDetector(
                      key: ObjectKey(videoController),
                      onVisibilityChanged: (visibility) {
                        if (visibility.visibleFraction == 0 && this.mounted) {
                          videoController.pause();
                        } else if (visibility.visibleFraction == 1) {
                          videoController.play();
                        }
                      },
                      child: VideoPlayer(videoController)),
                )),
          ),
```

Comment: I couldn't find the 'VisibilityDetector' widget and SDK doesn't detect it! Also, I don't see it in the flutter widget library.

Comment: Sorry you can find VisibilityDetector here https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector if you want to use else simple skip this.